# Is it possible to retrieve Google's complete index of my site?

Tags: search-engine

I'm managing a large website and would like to know which parts of it have been indexed by Google. I would like to be able to download the index as a file, so that I can parse and analyze it offline.

Is it possible to download the complete list of pages indexed by Google using Webmaster tools, Google Analytics or any other tool? Does any other search engine provide an option like this?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone can see all the pages of your site that have been indexed using the "site" command on google. Go to google.com and enter in the search box something like:

```
site:stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Yes, this much I know. 

However my point is to **download** the index. 

Google ironically blocks access by a robot and does not allow you to download these search results.

Also, these types of queries are limited to around 1000 results.